# MySQL: Delete multiple rows in a table based on a value in one selected field in one record of the same table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a single table as follows:

```
+---+----------+----------+---------+---------+
+ID + FIELD 1  + FIELD 2  + FIELD 3 + FIELD 4 +
+---+----------+----------+---------+---------+
+ 1 +  AAA     +  1234    +  ABC    +   Y     +
+ 2 +  AAA     +  1234    +  DEF    +         +
+ 3 +  AAA     +  1234    +  GHI    +         +
+ 4 +  BBB     +  1234    +  ABC    +         +
+ 5 +  CCC     +  1234    +  JKL    +         +
+---+----------+----------+---------+---------+
```

I have a process running that may set FIELD4 to "Y" and then a second process that checks for the value of 'Y' in a FIELD4.

I need to write a query (or queries probably) that will delete the record where FIELD4 = 'Y', but then also delete all other records where FIELD1 is of the same value to that of the originally deleted record.

For the record, FIELD4 will eventually become a check box and the MySQL required will be called from within a PHP script.  With this in mind, if the solution involves PHP this would not be an issue.

I've had a good search around PHP and MySQL sites and forums, but can't locate a One to Many deletion.  Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with following query:

```sql
delete from table
where FIELD1 in (
    select a.FIELD1
    from (select * from table) a 
    where a.FIELD4='Y'
);
```

Comment: Skills there LolCoder, you've nailed it bang on!  I must have tried so many variations and not hit upon this one.  I truly appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a Delete Select statement. Its basicly a select statement in a delete query. for example:

```
DELETE FROM `tablename` WHERE FIELD1 IN ( SELECT FIELD1 FROM `tablename` WHERE FIELD4 = `Y` )   );
```